# Excel VBA click on a link on a webpage - access denied

Tags: excel, vba

what I'm trying to achieve from Excel VBA is:

1. open a webpage and search for a specific form and input
2. fill the input and submit the form through a link  tag
3. search the new webpage generated by that submitted form.

Tasks 1 is done, and I'm trying to figure out why i'm getting an error 'ACCESS DENIED -2147024891 error' when the link is clicked.

My code so far for 1 and 2 :

```
Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim cp12Element As HTMLInputTextElement
Dim formElement As HTMLFormElement
Dim response As String

With http
    .Open "GET", "http://me.intra-dmu-13.dv.mes.reseau.intra/conformite/SoutienConformite/AcafWeb/AdrsGDI.asp?CP12=" & cp12, False
    .send
    
    If .Status <> 200 Then
        MsgBox "Error, the file number entered is invalid.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    response = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
End With

html.body.innerHTML = response
html.getElementsByName("CP12").Item(0).Value = "AAAA010101A1"
html.getElementsByClassName("lien").Item(0).Click    <--- ERROR
' html.getElementsByName("fAdrs").Item(0).submit   <--- generate the same error
```

The form's name is 'fAdrs' and there is only 1 input 'CP12'.
The form's method is POST.

The HTML code of the page :

```
<form name="fAdrs" method="post" action="AdrsGDI.asp?CP12=XXXX010101A1&Rech=Y">
   <input type=hidden name="Rech" value="1">    
   <table ID="Table3">              
     <tr>
       <td class="cell-login">
         <table class="NomChamps" ID="Table5">
           <tr>
             <td>
               <table class="NomChamps" ID="Table5">
                 <tr>
                   <td>CP12 :</td>
                   <td>
                     <input class="champs" type="text" name="CP12" value="">
                   </td>
                 </tr>
              </table>
             </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <table class="NomChamps" ID="Table5">        
         <tr height="15">
           <td class="cell-login">
             <a class="lien" href="javascript:DoSubmit();">SEARCH</a>               
           </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The function DoSubmit just a call a validation function and then submit the form.

Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to treat XMLHTTP, and the content returned stored in an HTMLDocument, as if you were using a browser. There is no page opening or clicking etc. You request the page and parse content depending on what is returned. You need to use the dev tools in browser, when doing this form submission manually, to see what is actually going on, then try and mimic that with XMLHTTP. Not sure whether you will need 1 or more than 1 requests as I haven't tried your code inferred process manually.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks @QHarr for taking the times to enlighten me.